# How can one express "to save" in Esperanto?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

There seem to be several words in Esperanto that all correspond to the English verb *to save*. I can think of *ŝpari*, *savi* and *konservi*. In which situations should I use which ones? If you have other possible translations, please share them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- *savi* — to rescue from danger or preserve from the threat of loss; to provide salvation to

  - *savi ion al iu* — to rescue something for someone
- *ŝpari, rezervi* — to conserve, to save up (money, time, etc)

  - *ŝpari al iu* — to save someone (effort, etc)
- *konservi* — to have (or place) in safekeeping, to hang on to

  - *konservi dosieron* — to save a file
- *evitigi ion al iu* — to save someone from (making a mistake, etc), to help avoid
- *domaĝi* — to prefer to save (money, a possession from possible harm)
- *sekurigi* — to keep safe, to secure, to ensure

Comment: Talking of a file, then I should use _domaĝi_, since we normally save a file to preserve data from possible harm. Or is there another word to use?

Comment: To save a file: *konservi dosieron*. The word *domaĝi* is more along the lines of "be worried about, act differently on account of": *Ŝi preferis ne promeni sur la plaĝo, ĉar ŝi domaĝis siajn novajn ŝuojn.*